# Sending erc20 tokens using Web3js

Tags: ethereum, web3js, erc20

I have tried to send erc20 (Bela) from one address to another got tx id in a result, but this transaction is not appearing in any tx check services and no funds sent from my address.
code at the moment looks like this:

```js
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/PKEY'));


var myAddress = "0x4d0...";
var toAddress = "0xce6...";
var amount = web3.utils.toHex(5);

var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress).then(function(v){console.log(v); count = v});

var privateKey = new Buffer('pkey', 'hex');

//got from https://etherscan.io/address/0x2e98a6804e4b6c832ed0ca876a943abd3400b224#code
var abiArray = '';

var contractAddress = '0x2e98a6804e4b6c832ed0ca876a943abd3400b224';
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, {from: myAddress});

var rawTransaction = {
    "from":myAddress,
    "gasPrice":"0x098bca5a00",
    "gasLimit":"0xcb05",
    "to":contractAddress,
    "value":"0x0",
    "data":contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).encodeABI(),
    "nonce":web3.utils.toHex(count)
};
var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction);
transaction.sign(privateKey);

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'), function (err, hash) {
    console.log(err, hash);
});
```

Comment: A couple (possible) issues I see: 1) Your nonce may be incorrect as you appear to be trying to set `count` both synchronously and asynchronously. It looks like you're using web3js 1.0, so you must use the asynch callback. Make sure to handle setting `count` through your callback correctly before building `rawTransaction`. 2) BELA is an 18 decimal token. You need to send 5e18 as the amount. There may be other issues as well, but this is just a quick glance.

Comment: @AdamKipnis, yes you are right, both suggested approaches are helpful!
many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update the "to" address within the transaction object using contract._address